# Simple DNS Modifications, Directing to CDN

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, subdomain, cloudflare, cdn

I'm reading through [this guide](https://www.incapsula.com/cdn-guide/what-is-cdn-how-it-works.html) which is quite thorough and helpful, but I've come across one paragraph that's stumping me.

> For your root domain, you'll change its A record to point to one of the CDN's IP ranges. For each subdomain, modify its CNAME record to point to a CDN-provided subdomain address (e.g., ns1.cdn.com). In both cases, this results in the DNS routing all visitors to your CDN instead of being directed to your original server. - See more at: https://www.incapsula.com/cdn-guide/what-is-cdn-how-it-works.html#sthash.f0v6pdOz.dpuf

1. The fact that you handle subdomains differently from root domains seems strange to me. Why am I using CNAME for subdomains, and A for root domain?
2. Why am I using A or CNAME records at all? Shouldn't I just be changing the nameservers in my domain control panel to those of the CDN?

Comment: The CDN handles web traffic, not nameserver traffic.

Answer (score 1):

1. You could use `A` records for them all, but you should use `CNAME` only on subdomains. That's because when you have a `CNAME` record, you can't have ANY other type of records on the same hostname. The root of your domain usually needs to have `MX` and `TXT` records for mail, not to even mention the `NS` records for the name servers, etc. (See [RFC 1912, 2.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1912#section-2.4).)
2. You can't just point your `NS` to the CDN's name servers, because they don't have your domain configured there. In order to make this work they should have their name servers configured as [*authoritative* name servers](https://www.dnsknowledge.com/whatis/authoritative-name-server/) for your domain.

Comment: CloudFlare prefers that you point you DNS domain at them directly, which lets them do DNS tricks such as return a dynamic result for the apex-record. This gets around the inability to CNAME a apex.  I'm surprised to see a CDN guide say to A-record the apex to a CDN IP; those IPs are often considered dynamic so a direct mapping like that is risky.